# Cannot generate data Using EXCEL VBA(run time error 424)

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I am trying to retrieve the Data from Oracle using Excel VBA, but I am getting `"run time error 424. object required"`. PFB source code. I am so new to Excel VBA. I appreciate your help.

```
Sub Generate_Data()
Dim str As String
Dim UID As String
Dim PWD As String
Dim Server As String
UID = "userid" 'Enter the User ID
PWD = "pwd" 'Enter the password
Server = "server" 'This comes from your TNSNames.ora file
str = "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE= & Server & ;Persist Security Info=True;USER ID= & UID & ;PASSWORD= & PWD &"
Set cnn = CreateObject(“ADODB.Connection”)
cnn.Open str
Set RS = CreateObject(“ADODB.Recordset”)
Row = 5
col = 5
numRs = RS.Fields.Count
num = 0
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM H1.TRADE_LOT_BASIS WHERE TO_CHAR(BOOK_VALUE_DATE,'YYYY')>=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')"
    RS.Open strSQL, cnn
    Do Until RS.EOF
    Do While num < numRs
    Cells(Row, col + num).Value = RS(num)
    num = num + 1
    Loop
    num = 0
    Row = Row + 1
    RS.moveNext
    Loop
    RS.Close
    cnn.Close
    End Sub"
```

Comment: On which line do you have the error?

Comment: i am having error on this line. Set cnn = CreateObject(“ADODB.Connection”)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
```